# dr racket code error beginning student language

Tags: racket

I am writing a function that consumes two images and produces true if the first is larger than the second
 here is my code

```
 (require 2htdp/image)

  (check-expect(image1 30 40)false)
    (check-expect(image1 50 20)true)

(define(image1 x y)
 (begin
 ( circle x "solid" "blue")

(circle y "solid" "blue")
  (if(> x y)
     "true"
     "false")))


(image1 500 100)
```

But it is showing the same error again and again by highlighting this portion of the code  ->(circle y "solid" "blue") the error is-> define: expected only one expression for the function body, but found 2 extra parts kindly tell me what is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values `true` and `false` are simply written as `true` and `false`.

```
(define (image1 x y)
  (circle x "solid" "blue")
  (circle y "solid" "blue")
  (if (> x y)
      true
      false))
```

Note that the your function doesn't use the images, so you can write

```
(define (image1 x y)
  (if (> x y)
      true
      false))
```

But I guess it was just an example.

UPDATE

You can use local definitions to give names to temporary values:

```
(define (image1 x y)
  (local 
    [(define c1 (circle x "solid" "blue"))
     (define c2 (circle y "solid" "blue"))]
  (if (> x y)
      true
      false)))
```

UPDATE

```
(define (larger? image1 image2)
  (and (> (image-width  image1) (image-width  image2) 
       (> (image-height image1) (image-height image2)))
```

UPDATE

Here is a complete example:

```
(define circle1 (circle 20 "solid" "blue"))
(define circle2 (circle 30 "solid" "blue"))

(define (larger? image1 image2)
  (and (> (image-width  image1) (image-width  image2))
       (> (image-height image1) (image-height image2))))

(larger? circle1 circle2)
```

Comment: my aim is to use two images and compare this is the best way i coud do thats why .is there any other way round????

Comment: You can use local definitions to give names to temporary values. See updated answer.

Comment: it is saying this function is not  defined ,the local one what to do now. shud i add something at the top??

Comment: Local is available in the intermediate language: http://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/intermediate.html?q=local#%28form._%28%28lib._lang%2Fhtdp-intermediate..rkt%29._local%29%29

Comment: i want to do it in BSL so any suggestions on how shud i proceed

Comment: I have added an `larger?` that uses `image-width` and `image-height` to determine if `image1` is larger than `image2`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80833/discussion-between-user3371423-and-soegaard).

Comment: If you want to chat about Racket then visit the IRC channel #racket at freenode.  http://racket-lang.org/irc-chat.html

Comment: i have aaded an image pls see it.The problem is that i am predefining the images which shud not be the case as it is a function so what shud i do to add standard variable

Comment: I have added a complete example that shows how to use larger?. It needs two images as input.